# how to disable a button after first click?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How to disable a button after clicking it in Odoo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of Odoo module use state for this kind of problem. the general idea of it that you must have a field and the button is displayed based on the value of that field.

Ex:

```py
  # in you model
  bool_field = fields.Boolean('Same text', default=False)
```

In your view:

```xml
 <button name="some_method"......... attrs="{'invisible': [('bool_field', '=', True)]}" />
 ...
 ...
 ...
 <!-- keep the field invisible because i don't need the user to see
      it, the value of this field is for technical purpuse -->
 <field name="bool_field" invisible="1"/>
```

In your model:

```py
 @api.multi
 def some_method(self):
    # in this method i will make sure to change the value of the 
    # field to True so the button is not visible any more for user
    self.bool_field = True
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

So if you all ready have a field that the button change it's value you can use it directly
or create a special field for this purpose.

Comment: this is invisible not disabled

Comment: Yes it's how most odoo developers do, I don't know if readonly work on the button